# angular ng-repeat display value from array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, materialize

I'm new with angular, and I m trying to build a dynamic pricing table

I have this :

```
    <li ng-repeat="option in optionsActives"  class="collection-item {{option.categorie}}"><div>{{option.services}}<a class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a></div></li>
```

output : [{"titre":"titre","desc":"description"},{"titre":"titre a","desc":"description a"}]

But I need to output {{option.services.descr}}

Here's my fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/shutterlab/vnss3mf0/3/

I would like to display value inside services array (array  inside items)
but I can get the value from 
{{option.services.titre}} {{option.services.descr}}
Inside a ng-repeat ?

What can i do ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular you can nest `ng-repeat`'s

You simply do:

```
<div ng-repeat="optionItem in option.services">{{ optionItem.desc }}</div>
```

I've updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vnss3mf0/4/

Comment: Thanks, I used   
<div ng-repeat="option in optionsActives">
        <li ng-repeat="optionItem in option.services" class="collection-item {{option.categorie}}"><div>{{optionItem.titre}}<a class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a></div></li>
      </div>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to display the content of the services array, so you just nest another ng-repeat. Example:

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="service in item.services">
         {{service.titre}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjneg43b/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: `{{option.services[0].desc}}`

Answer (score 0):

add a  .desc

```
<li ng-repeat="option in optionsActives" class="collection-item {{option.categorie}}">
        <div>{{option.services.desc}}<a class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">done</i></a></div>
      </li>
```